# Проверка существования пользователя, oauth2

Tags: веб-программирование, oauth2

Есть приложение написанное на PHP, в котороместь закрытый раздел для доступа к разделу необходима авторизация. У приложения уже есть какое-то колличество пользователей. Необходимо "прикрутить" к проекту авторизацию через соц сети.

В принципе ничего сложного, но меня волнует такая ситуация:

Если пользователь, который регистрировался уже давно, стандартным сопсобом решит авторизоваться в системе то как распознать его? Ведь есть такие соц сети где не всегда был обязательный e-mail и даже по нему не всегда можно точно знать, что это именно этот пользователь (можно специально подменить его).

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучший вариант - искать пользователя по email. Для этого в `scope` запроса на авторизацию надо добавить email. Для vk ссылка будет примерно такая:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=*app_id*&redirect_uri=*login_redirect*&scope=email
```

(значения между звездочками заменить на ваши данные).
Тогда после подтверждения пользователя в ответе будет доступен его email, дальше по нему искать пользователя в БД.

Facebook предоставляет email без проблем, vk при таком запросе уведомит пользователя о том, что сайт запрашивает его адрес эл. почты.
В vk пользователь может не указать email, при этом идентифицировать его фактически невозможно. Instagram email не предоставляет в принципе. В данной ситуации выход только в отдельном интерфейсе, где пользователь может самостоятельно связывать аккаунты. Например, если он уже авторизован через email и хочет привязать vk, ему надо пройти авторизацию через vk. Полученные идентификационные данные однозначно будут связаны с текущим email.

Соц.сети требуют подтверждения email, поэтому можно не беспокоиться о его подмене.